# How can I set the user picture from a file in Mavericks?

Tags: macos, user-account

How can I load an image from a file as my user image in Mavericks?  The interface changed so the [Mountain Lion instructions](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11469) aren't applicable, and the [Mavericks instructions](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14412) don't cover loading it from a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the Users System preferences.

Select the user and then drag your file onto the current image.